# Why is the kerning wrong in the TeX.SX logo/banner?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, logo

I really love the beautiful shaded TeX.SX logo — I think it makes tex.stackexchange.com one of the best looking of all the StackExchange sites.

[image]

But I am curious why the kerning is wrong? (By that I mean it doesn't follow Knuth's kerning of the TeX logo.) Should it not look more like this?—

[image]

The latter shows the E lowered by 1 pixel and the T and X each moved 6 pixels closer to the E.  It's subtle, but it feels more "TeX-like" to me that way.  Anyone agree/disagree?

Comment: It's good to see them next to each other.  The properly kerned one gets my vote.  @jin, any chance of fixing this?

Comment: Nice finding! `:)` On a funny note, we need a new [swag package](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/tex-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users) with the proper kerning in the logo to be resent to all top users; this time *I'm in the second page*. `:P`

Comment: I'll fix this. I tried to mimic the kerning as closely as possible from what I saw on the web when I designed the logo. The community didn't object to what I had so I assumed I did it correctly.

Comment: @Jin Speaking for myself, I wouldn't have noticed if no-one had brought it to my attention, but now that someone *has*, it glares out at me.  Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: I hadn't noticed it myself until I hand-kerned a version of `\TeX`, `\LaTeX`, and `\XeTeX` for HTML text using CSS in late December. Then it suddenly stood out to me. It's really funny how that works...once you see something, you really can't un-see it.

Comment: @AndrewStacey http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/kerning.png

Comment: Now we need new [swag packages][1] with the correct kerning.


  [1]: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/tex-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users/2342#2342

Comment: ... not meant to be taken seriously

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have deployed a fix for this on dev. It will be live after our next production build. I put cache breaker in css so no need to hard refresh browser to see the new logo change.

Comment: Cool — can't wait to see it!
Dumb question: how does one view the dev site?

Comment: @ToddLehman you can't. it's for me only :)

Comment: @Jin I can see the fixed logo now. It looks nice. Did you make the shadows inside the letters stronger too?

Comment: @N.N. I tweaked the angle of the inner shadow a bit. It's a straight cast from top now, before it was slanted angle.

Comment: @Jin Thanks for the fix! It looks like the braces now are further away from the TeX -- could they be moved a bit towards the middle?

Answer (score 27):

Here's the logo as defined by DEK at `\magnification 6000` run from `plain.tex`.  Judge for yourself.

[image: original TeX logo, magnified to 60pt]

**Addendum:** DEK wrote a [brief article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb07-2/tb15knutlogo.pdf) for TUGboat with his recommendations for "correcting" the kerning for the logo in different (`cm`) fonts.  He also mentions some (limited) experiences with non-`cm` fonts.

Comment: Exactly! Tighter kerning. :)

Comment: I've got to go with @ToddLehman on this one, his version looks more like that then the one at the top of the screen.

Comment: If only you'd written this with capital letters at the start of sentences, we could have regarded it as the Official Line on how to write TeX!

Comment: @Andrew -- oh, okay.  i guess this one's non-controversial enough to be considered official.

Comment: Great!  Now we can tell @Jin that it's *official* that the design is wrong.

Comment: Wow, I assumed the edit wasn't from barbara! but if I understand what the page was telling me, it was. I didn't know she had any capital letters on her keyboard.

Comment: hi, @David.  i actually do have capital letters on my keyboard, but i can save a keystroke now and then by not using them.  <g>

Comment: I once had an edit denied because I went through and added capitals to one of your answers, not knowing that was a stylistic choice.