# Update the TeX Community Blog logo

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, blog, logo

Now that the tex.sx logo [has *the real* kerning](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/why-is-the-kerning-wrong-in-the-tex-sx-logo-banner), the Community Blog logo should be updated, too. Compare:

[image: tex.sx logo]
(tex.sx logo)

[image: Community Blog logo]
(blog logo)

I stick to my [comment to Jin's answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2229/4012) though, that the braces should be moved a bit closer to the *TeX*, preferably on both/all logos.

Comment: @PauloCereda: That would apply to http://tex.blogoverflow.com/files/2011/11/textalk1.png as well, of course `:)`.

Comment: Done! `:)` New logo deployed, thanks! `:)` The old logo is no more. It has ceased to be, it's expired and gone to meet its maker. The old logo's a stiff. Bereft of life, it rests in peace. Its metabolic processes are now history. The old logo's off the twig, it's kicked the bucket, it's shuffled off its mortal coil, run down the curtain and joined the bleedin' choir invisibile. This is now an ex-logo. `:)` *(Apologies to John and Graham)*

Comment: @PauloCereda When I view http://tex.blogoverflow.com/ the logo has the old (bad) kerning.

Comment: @N.N.: Yes, you are right. `:(` Unfortunately, the blog logo is beyond our scope (the TeXtalk one is deployed under our blog user account, so it was easy for me to fix). I'll drop another comment for Jin. `:)`

Comment: @Jin: Could you kindly replace our old blog logo for the correct one? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: I don't think Jin has been involved in this thread yet, so he won't get your `@` note.

Comment: @doncherry: Oh true. `:(` I always get confused with that. `:)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A fix for this logo issue has been pushed, and should be active at the next build of the blog network.

Comment: Thank you very much, Grace. `:)`