# TeX meta art clip (TeX written on torn paper) has wrong kerning

Tags: bug, status-completed

I saw an ad "visit TeX meta" and TeX was kerned the same way the old version of TeX symbol on this page used to be kerned;  with T touching corner of E and E touching the corner of X.

The issue was brought up in [update the tex community blog logo](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/update-the-tex-community-blog-logo) and was corrected. But apparently its ghost still lives.

Comment: This will hold for a variety of community adds: [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2011](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1184/5764), [Community Promotion Ads - 2012](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2046/5764)

Comment: I'll fix them, I promise! `:)` Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=3257613#3257613 !!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Done! `:)` I've updated all ads I could:

- Answer the unanswered sessions
- Visit Meta
- From answers to packages
- TeX community blog
- TeX community polls

Thanks!